# '...' expected.ts(1005) and No overload matches this call

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, styled-components

Hello fellow programmers !

After a day of setting up React app with TypeScript, webPack, Babel, ESLint, Styled Components etc. I am so close..

I am stuck with two errors and I cant reslove them...
Can some awesome person out there point me in the right direction .

For the first issue I have followed this guide without result :
https://binyamin.medium.com/using-typescript-with-styled-components-35950e196e9c

First issue:
[image]
[image]

Second Issue:
[image]

eslintrc:

[image]

tsconfig:

[image]

Comment: Next time please avoid posting images of code, post the actual code with formatting. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Absolutely, thought the picture would be easier to overlook :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just a syntax error, read more about [JSX in depth](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper). Check [prettier output](https://prettier.io/playground/#N4Igxg9gdgLgprEAuEAdKAeAfOjB1AJwEMAHEuAgAlPKOKjDgF5ga46iG4BfSgehyYAggBsKMSiKIAjOCKaoQACTkiIi6mXb1GCkAEsoAM3UgB6dHz6UAzkQC2cSgApFAOg+U4AD3Jh4ACaKAJS4hGxUwB5urFocXNy85sJiBBJRHsBSsiJIlIoqImqKADSatDpweYqGJoqJ-IKUzS2tzRgCICUgECQw+tA2yKB0BBAA7gAKdAhDKEQi40QAnkPd0sRgANZwMADKJERghgDmyDAEAK5w3XD2sgEBcAEAMpwnl0QncABiEAT2IgwfpQM7zS4wCBdEAACxg9hEeBh+ngNkOjD2sxR+gAbijlshwDY1gYoDZxJNiCdAcgjAtyd0AFY2bwAIU2O32DjgL0McFp9JuIGZ3j2pzEAEVLhB4AKRAyQIcCOSCITpDI5NCSARDDA8PoAjAYcgABwABm62og5PCJEJ2rgKpx-O6AEdpfBKb05iAiDYALRQODPZ7Qghwd36cOUr40pB0+VC8n2fTnK5J8VwKUy-nxwXdGAyfWG41IABMBeI+hEpwAwhB7HGQI6AKzQy7kgAqMjmCYVOOuAEkoE9YHswDq+kIR3sYMsxHLyYkgA).

```js
<>
  <Wrapper appearance={appearance} />
  <Alert label="Hello" appearance="info" />
  // same ("... expected")
  <Wrapper {...{ appearance }} />
  <Alert {...{ label: "Hello", appearance: "info" }} />
</>
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved the first issue , looks just a little odd I would say, but I guess i'm just unfamiliar with React and spread Operator 

Answer (score 0):

Second Issue was solved by creating a type that only contained the prop needed in the wrapper class:

```
interface IWrapperTypes {
    appearance: "success" | "warning" | "info" | "danger" | "notification";
}

type WrapperTypes = IWrapperTypes;
const Wrapper = styled.div<WrapperTypes> //....
```